# If Data connection is on then show a dialog. otherwise not

Tags: android

If data connection is on show a dialog box. How can I create.I am new developer so please give. MainActivity code and xml view code.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method you can use to validate whether a data connection is available or not:

```
public static boolean isDataConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

If this returns true then you can do your logic to display a dialog box. There are plenty of examples available on StackOverflow for using dialog boxes so I will trust you can locate those and implement your functionality successfully.